# What is effective airflow?

Tags: aerodynamics, wing

[image]

As I understood, when the relative airflow meets the wing it changes, and the resulting flow is called effective airflow?

Comment: Could it signify that we are taking into account the differences in apparent relative wind direction from nose to tail or wingtip to wingtip,  caused by the airplane rotating about one or more axes?

Comment: Some context would be helpful.  There probably is no absolute defintion.

Comment: We have effective angle of attack that lies between chord of foil and effective airflow. But what is this effective airflow.

Comment: In my opinion the source ought to define it.  Is it the exact direction a smoke streamline would approach the wing, or something else?  If yes to the former then it is affected by all the things mentioned in your question and in my comment.

Comment: Looks like " relative airflow" is meant to be the undisturbed relative wind and "effective airflow" includes the upwash in front of the wing.

Comment: Hm, I would actually guess that the effective airflow takes into account the fact that the airplane is increasing in altitude. So the relative airflow is basically ground speed + wind, and relative airflow is what the airplane actually feels. I could be wrong, of course!

Comment: @Jimmy - you are right- the diagram is not compatible with my answer re upwash.  Deleting.  We need more context.  Maybe the diagram is for the left wing of a plane that is rolling to the right.  Or maybe the diagram is a horizontal stabilizer in the wing's downwash.    "I think you mean downwash instead of upwash? This may be related to the downwash produced from lifting line vortices. --Jimmy"